# Share session between two MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an older application that has an ActionResult function that I would like to include in another newer application.

I have found that I can add the older controller as a reference, Instantiate the controller as an object, and then call the ActionResult function accordingly, like so:

```
public ActionResult test()
    {
        OlderApplication.Controllers.PatronController temp = new OlderApplication.Controllers.PatronController();

        return temp.Index();
    }
```

My problem lies in the fact that inside temp.Index() it references the Session, and it is coming up as null instead of having a value that should exist.  Can I make session available this way?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: The Yahoo tells me everything is OK.  I Tagged this post ASP.NET-MVC, Sorry that wasn't enough for you.

Comment: Actually is was the one who changed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've given you don't have two MVC applications - you have a single application that shares the same codebase. An "application" is defined by the webserver, but I digress.

The reason the Session within `temp` is null is because you aren't initializing the Controller correctly - Controllers are not POCOs, they require initialization. Call `temp.Initialize()`, however you'll need to create the `RequestContext` instance yourself, like so:

```
RequestContext context = new RequestContext( this.Context, this.RouteData );
OlderApplication.Controllers.PatronController oldController = new OlderApplication.Controllers.PatronController();
oldController.Initialize( context );

return oldController.Index();
```

Although if you're going through this step, you might as well just wire up your old controller into your Area Registration and/or URI Routing tables, thus negating the need to write this code.

Comment: I get what you're saying with the first part.  2 MVC "projects" would be the terminology I'd want to use?

Comment: Dai - I am having an issue calling the oldController.Initialize( context ) method.  When I look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.108).aspx I see that it tells me "This method cannot be called directly."

Comment: Furthermore - this is the error I get when i try and build: Cannot access protected member 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)' via a qualifier of type 'OldController.Controllers.PatronController'; the qualifier must be of type 'NewController.Controllers.AdminController' (or derived from it)

Comment: Dang - I'm stumped. I cannot help you further, sorry :(

Comment: FYI - Initialize is protected so I couldn't call it the way you mentioned.  I added a public function to OldController, though, which was able to call the initialize function.

Answer (score 1):

As Dai pointed out you're not creating the controller correctly.
I would suggest using the controller factory to create your controller.

```
var oldController  = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(Request.RequestContext, "Patron");
```

Comment: This would work if my controller was in the same project (I said application above, Dai corrected me), but as these are separate projects I need to do it the way Dai detailed below.

Comment: @NeilM. I don't think so - the factory will find your controller by reflection even if it is in a referenced project. Using the factory is better because it's the standard way MVC does it. If you've plugged an IoC container by a custom factory for example just new-ing the controller may cause you some trouble.